# Cassandra 3.3 - cluster node - irregular behavior

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a Cassandra Cluster conformed with the nodes 
{ 192.168.120.57, 192.168.120.58, 192.168.120.59 }, **with replication factor of 2**

I detected the node 192.168.120.59 was behaving irregularly
-> The service was running (sudo service cassandra status)
-> The nodetool also told me that the node was running

```
XXXX@cassandra-prod03:~$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.120.57  4.05 GB    256          ?       6d0f5961-a600-42c2-8ba5-5b6ebff52ceb  rack1
UN  192.168.120.58  4.4 GB     256          ?       53bc77ff-50b3-4bf0-bd55-17e2bb7c8208  rack1
UN  192.168.120.59  2.77 GB    256          ?       03d8d7fd-1d86-4034-a537-9915adb0d4b3  rack1
```

**BUT** ->  I couldn't connect by DevCenter (the last time I tried I could and the cassandra.yml hasn't changed)

I looked into the log of this node (192.168.120.59), and showed:

```
ERROR [HintsDispatcher:1] 2016-06-23 16:57:01,827 HintsDispatchExecutor.java:224 - Failed to dispatch hints file 6d0f5961-a600-42c2-8ba5-5b6ebff52ceb-1465184315371-1.hints: file is corrupted ({})
ERROR [HintsDispatcher:1] 2016-06-23 16:57:01,830 CassandraDaemon.java:195 - Exception in thread Thread[HintsDispatcher:1,1,main]
ERROR [HintsDispatcher:1] 2016-06-23 16:57:01,834 StorageService.java:470 - Stopping gossiper
ERROR [HintsDispatcher:1] 2016-06-23 16:57:03,842 StorageService.java:480 - Stopping native transport
```

In the other nodes, the log showed many many times:

```
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-06-24 07:56:21,551 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /192.168.120.59 with status shutdown - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-06-24 07:56:22,552 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /192.168.120.59 with status shutdown - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-06-24 07:56:23,552 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /192.168.120.59 with status shutdown - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-06-24 07:56:24,553 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /192.168.120.59 with status shutdown - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-06-24 07:56:25,553 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /192.168.120.59 with status shutdown - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-06-24 07:56:26,553 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /192.168.120.59 with status shutdown - alive false
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2016-06-24 07:56:27,554 Gossiper.java:336 - Convicting /192.168.120.59 with status shutdown - alive false
```

These are the things I have done and which didn't work:
1) reboot the machine.
2) nodetool repair.

```
XXXXs@cassandra-prod03:~$ nodetool repair
[2016-06-23 17:07:37,582] Starting repair command #1, repairing keyspace recommendersjobs with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: false, incremental: true, job threads: 1, ColumnFamilies: [], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 512)
Jun 23, 2016 5:53:57 PM ClientCommunicatorAdmin Checker-run
WARNING: Failed to check the connection: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Exception occurred during clean-up. java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
error: [2016-06-23 18:06:22,229] JMX connection closed. You should check server log for repair status of keyspace recommendersjobs(Subsequent keyspaces are not going to be repaired).
-- StackTrace --
java.io.IOException: [2016-06-23 18:06:22,229] JMX connection closed. You should check server log for repair status of keyspace recommendersjobs(Subsequent keyspaces are not going to be repaired).
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.RepairRunner.handleConnectionFailed(RepairRunner.java:97)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.progress.jmx.JMXNotificationProgressListener.handleNotification(JMXNotificationProgressListener.java:86)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.handleNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:275)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$SendNotifJob.run(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:352)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$1.execute(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:337)
at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:248)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.sendNotification(RMIConnector.java:441)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.access$1200(RMIConnector.java:121)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RMIClientCommunicatorAdmin.gotIOException(RMIConnector.java:1531)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RMINotifClient.fetchNotifs(RMIConnector.java:1352)
```

3) nodetool scrub.

After this I followed this page https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_noderestart_t.html

On the node that presented the irregular behaviour:
1) Deleted all tables
2) Copy and Paste the tables that were in the snapshot sub-directory
3) Restarted cassandra service (`sudo service cassandra start`)

Now the Dev-Center can connect

4) I Ran `nodetool repair` again, and it seems that is not finishing. It has been running for more than 3 hours and is still in 0% (but for now didn't throw the other error), but I think it is not working.

```
XXXX@cassandra-prod03:/var/lib/cassandra/data/recommendersjobs$ nodetool repair
[2016-06-24 12:24:13,901] Starting repair command #2, repairing keyspace recommendersjobs with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: false, incremental: true, job threads: 1, ColumnFamilies: [], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 512)
[2016-06-24 12:24:17,235] Repair session 7990e900-3a30-11e6-9861-e998758604bf for range [(-4211712190859502280,-4203992560184719114], (-8318576077833367495,-8293862912754480840], (6846385493332587078,6848188842228182830], (-6460899805527117383,-6451580681320322560], (-927549969226058129,-890279568362794135], (-6984061332646781425,-6971866923830433843], (4166814791483192953,4181831925595728309], (212986607214778070,288868023576418487], (656453115636318699,670358990995510048], (-3857111065907140708,-3844748631754416189], (-731643009820930522,-708535538994856284], (-3646398519882341977,-3630383383747491969], (-4215258070829115921,-4211712190859502280], (6972519766285293067,6983272857539313387], (8698322395242654268,8707318407090795417], (-1229710138608978352,-1142107267252652523], (-6043663680829718954,-6000947666680635781], (-2555062915045199657,-2518876915835081063], (700476075055800053,714305291929584762], (-9040157763677832405,-9035752029446223323], (-5508447172120753932,-5486202973508763691], (685259738113005224,700476075055800053], (-3498127715533695144,-3481009398659298196], (-6642818648542557724,-6636310914487378937], (8434600097698749124,8447388029675461333], (-9196939878235591876,-9176601682787902008], (-8392736270165548628,-8358469817741800124], (2668692603556301942,2674434559513729415], (-1868370051056061493,-1860700618558449042], (-6090102443758865946,-6081413019910708044], (-1234056662103299181,-1233526281479424892], (5500764053339166116,5524556889632227041], (-2343395791776959523,-2315566773401476532], (-1401161284995746969,-1393787270658712827], (-2204381944261735990,-2170477179223028079], (6158419946524545293,6171118529963906232], (-4713529768344258113,-4662557763507006574], (-6844075271953818452,-6821121360440227129], (-2945271950056514025,-2943444578534843676], (336935533896784347,357900664320554816], (-3228825867554770158,-3208435083108021414], (-4955223362385024239,-4912831044277064162], (4255028482041276438,4266791030997837989], (6476681916885657705,6500903072598398827], (-1233526281479424892,-1229710138608978352], (1478830670694875260,1516022971169730278], (5055515752742518226,5080231569691472194], (-8220031638992810484,-8180158125318738371], (-1644262187188908209,-1640818085920683524], (-4203992560184719114,-4201062514351678359], (-5222304299920694120,-5219839223573200521], (-8773724135260117843,-8764792082520695033], (-1355888553876954583,-1337212328034401607], (4736203535340725934,4798689233015535742], (1271210285313194340,1296150437356677365], (-3540891434049035738,-3498615337040509123], (-6469678775729021799,-6460899805527117383], (6720989190599823387,6725081429318018351], (-3498615337040509123,-3498127715533695144], (-3146863944770153663,-3146145879742664566], (1516022971169730278,1543205759172249070], (2435469497781312092,2442862581422161803], (-6451580681320322560,-6450897957558236116], (6401972194395279212,6422279168069398956], (-3185403021559141625,-3146863944770153663], (714305291929584762,737464206890275575], (-8358469817741800124,-8348341616724830280], (1175374807063094969,1214972878391460620], (-7604581392807650182,-7599009809842308024], (737464206890275575,753307058766478061], (6142712373291735013,6158419946524545293], (-4780493053770543287,-4715780574795279713], (-6475595045987094984,-6472782860721811368], (-6000947666680635781,-5984299660747839008], (1296150437356677365,1341203791801750057], (-708535538994856284,-698490751868803865], (7377888475905026189,7453466617724696329], (-6634208348348544983,-6608369916989089358], (6422279168069398956,6425564550565269465], (7864684753798709404,7865351483298068861], (-1142107267252652523,-1130763472498460650], (2661263629361374231,2668692603556301942], (5080231569691472194,5114813438584055434], (-3146145879742664566,-3133020507157500012], (-8847809439930946447,-8773724135260117843], (-7455563937756770941,-7393173741279261649], (-8001929233768101133,-7997359338916453120], (-3208435083108021414,-3185403021559141625], (-8504346858359312144,-8489394145547730314], (330577967974463458,336935533896784347], (7563807678381276197,7582113707662028389], (-8542082760751850432,-8504346858359312144], (-3554430985922725406,-3540891434049035738], (-5146821899868165131,-5132879094583817494], (-240050552784290962,-235772081518906038], (3192195406141461438,3232311876000191165], (4396701296202861119,4435447637968520477], (-6608369916989089358,-6589281199205137237], (-1981758794620356502,-1980394476029734464], (-3563262972235992519,-3554430985922725406], (-8237266126949227268,-8229088751363770412], (4603382773438618005,4650956890538380770], (7199369658829377994,7213887142216841811], (-4962133286795414966,-4960837410336448181], (5732306214090585629,5737923082195078719], (-1640818085920683524,-1638198095283336424], (2953772832389323874,2968606959459466094], (-1235736831018577452,-1234056662103299181], (-8489394145547730314,-8465866933095448418], (-8764792082520695033,-8742184848088246957], (8970234525288431416,8995803891393002810], (-8465866933095448418,-8446751642929552235], (-4836950976239959831,-4798814403290155024], (8821435912538079613,8871870554368996448], (-6636310914487378937,-6634208348348544983], (1127798841363210583,1175374807063094969], (1618461143046543312,1632362492578265392], (4994543089928849457,5055515752742518226], (1593785714944278507,1618461143046543312], (-8885929495137049667,-8847809439930946447], (7514316870399738740,7535648178040640648], (-7997359338916453120,-7884947734877215590], (6848188842228182830,6851091943952222998], (-7468624498429238352,-7467528674261593018], (-5420066870415394025,-5415525963610970555], (-1990341934536435876,-1981758794620356502], (-2119663304358780223,-2025913005077454264], (6951976975129490336,6972519766285293067], (4814028481954927072,4845532697727637101], (6905718428902118395,6951976975129490336], (2442862581422161803,2473486929810000384], (-7050886265796431130,-6984061332646781425], (899736981222314462,902246412094263205], (4181831925595728309,4186043100749193555], (5228334028316552580,5251807687845401107], (7453466617724696329,7514316870399738740], (-5313682991153179320,-5303078638925764028], (4435447637968520477,4466559239870893508], (-1326922053645316997,-1235736831018577452], (1401641821520873210,1444010990722687070], (1751424608310627366,1764837197082917798], (4501052626153108190,4556808478342919483], (4927485308468803128,4934126082298511287], (9034829150987061085,9125279489658634069], (8296589981550156872,8314630209670832253], (8448913759582599761,8531687930406385678], (-6946999157236744448,-6844075271953818452], (1444010990722687070,1478830670694875260], (8959600358987559211,8960859570137987260], (-1336371416389083059,-1326922053645316997], (-61295809418728622,-42017489632420450], (8969118191184771962,8970234525288431416], (1635093197288200819,1646180075666173338], (4934126082298511287,4936412559469748364], (1751396675459233161,1751424608310627366], (-8742184848088246957,-8729944250195454990], (-8229088751363770412,-8220031638992810484], (4598535296351629260,4603382773438618005], (-8174261525446719402,-8163507145438773646], (755491933174209966,772199007723251143], (-8624222028448607604,-8600591663798592212], (-7519020387526209046,-7508903488301733990], (753307058766478061,755491933174209966], (7582113707662028389,7704299093463733587], (8962972620592857243,8969118191184771962], (-3630383383747491969,-3629090531220364683], (-4468127887710219501,-4455300706501649674], (5852098730437702158,5901360113812253268], (-744327910454436920,-731643009820930522], (1911291563147302352,1937039485053092324], (6233932117267819795,6310871518339058610], (-890279568362794135,-887061681980670889], (-3679929070886276718,-3646398519882341977], (670358990995510048,685259738113005224], (4845532697727637101,4882596066849804097], (-6472782860721811368,-6469678775729021799], (-4715780574795279713,-4713529768344258113], (3078864489691764074,3115136329005690845], (9125279489658634069,9133717713662800417], (8960859570137987260,8962972620592857243], (9203390852073803003,-9222340996132828621], (4798689233015535742,4814028481954927072], (-6821121360440227129,-6777406043019946301], (6310871518339058610,6322362350826191135], (-4233493116436171657,-4215258070829115921], (3130822610289703870,3145528043810254358], (5114813438584055434,5123797488219630832], (-6081413019910708044,-6079621320236638978], (8447388029675461333,8448913759582599761], (-3795970094034238564,-3779568630549582632], (-8180158125318738371,-8174261525446719402], (-3844748631754416189,-3795970094034238564], (4113442287147808270,4131576074431163736], (4936412559469748364,4994543089928849457], (4466559239870893508,4501052626153108190], (-3263191959146785290,-3228825867554770158], (6766473197422691050,6766938926557171347], (-8899258035651035854,-8885929495137049667], (-5381097520433537861,-5313682991153179320], (6883419270850869410,6905718428902118395], (5303695175174121453,5306682210025644500], (-9176601682787902008,-9096402285624130055], (-5219839223573200521,-5146821899868165131], (7862240594123780934,7864684753798709404], (6425564550565269465,6447403433784268090], (8996665254881958342,9032628945801968053], (-4912831044277064162,-4902449072491610799], (-2025913005077454264,-1990341934536435876], (-7467528674261593018,-7455563937756770941], (-3293906917083373209,-3283303577982631091], (4186043100749193555,4255028482041276438], (-4902449072491610799,-4875492513338002087], (8531687930406385678,8562083491872293504], (-8600591663798592212,-8567258569010210224], (-6079621320236638978,-6077962914827619257], (-4960837410336448181,-4955223362385024239], (-7634134348451706917,-7604581392807650182], (1632362492578265392,1635093197288200819], (291067515209041750,330577967974463458], (7789905572870286790,7790287256445162065], (-8007287567032110044,-8001929233768101133], (-6971866923830433843,-6946999157236744448], (9032628945801968053,9034829150987061085], (-4798814403290155024,-4780493053770543287], (3905716352976079268,3920453505268467479], (8995803891393002810,8996665254881958342], (-1393787270658712827,-1355888553876954583], (6522490073023565012,6553480210988421066], (7162495952820208409,7199369658829377994], (4882596066849804097,4927485308468803128], (-5893410924582496350,-5858193870200257506], (8233960782654491894,8252708412304213777], (6725081429318018351,6766473197422691050], (-5303078638925764028,-5222304299920694120], (2376875294823216717,2379477119284337609], (-7393173741279261649,-7376038212607696986], (-1337212328034401607,-1336371416389083059], (902246412094263205,902703964241874282], (288868023576418487,291067515209041750], (1341203791801750057,1364316712425392743], (5199663539610295629,5228334028316552580], (6447403433784268090,6476681916885657705], (-3481009398659298196,-3391281017675748608], (4266791030997837989,4315496651682018963], (3115136329005690845,3130822610289703870], (-7599009809842308024,-7598746015885846943]] failed with error [repair #7990e900-3a30-11e6-9861-e998758604bf on recommendersjobs/postulationsbyuser, [(-4211712190859502280,-4203992560184719114], (-8318576077833367495,-8293862912754480840], (6846385493332587078,6848188842228182830], (-6460899805527117383,-6451580681320322560], (-927549969226058129,-890279568362794135], (-6984061332646781425,-6971866923830433843], (4166814791483192953,4181831925595728309], (212986607214778070,288868023576418487], (656453115636318699,670358990995510048], (-3857111065907140708,-3844748631754416189], (-731643009820930522,-708535538994856284], (-3646398519882341977,-3630383383747491969], (-4215258070829115921,-4211712190859502280], (6972519766285293067,6983272857539313387], (8698322395242654268,8707318407090795417], (-1229710138608978352,-1142107267252652523], (-6043663680829718954,-6000947666680635781], (-2555062915045199657,-2518876915835081063], (700476075055800053,714305291929584762], (-9040157763677832405,-9035752029446223323], (-5508447172120753932,-5486202973508763691], (685259738113005224,700476075055800053], (-3498127715533695144,-3481009398659298196], (-6642818648542557724,-6636310914487378937], (8434600097698749124,8447388029675461333], (-9196939878235591876,-9176601682787902008], (-8392736270165548628,-8358469817741800124], (2668692603556301942,2674434559513729415], (-1868370051056061493,-1860700618558449042], (-6090102443758865946,-6081413019910708044], (-1234056662103299181,-1233526281479424892], (5500764053339166116,5524556889632227041], (-2343395791776959523,-2315566773401476532], (-1401161284995746969,-1393787270658712827], (-2204381944261735990,-2170477179223028079], (6158419946524545293,6171118529963906232], (-4713529768344258113,-4662557763507006574], (-6844075271953818452,-6821121360440227129], (-2945271950056514025,-2943444578534843676], (336935533896784347,357900664320554816], (-3228825867554770158,-3208435083108021414], (-4955223362385024239,-4912831044277064162], (4255028482041276438,4266791030997837989], (6476681916885657705,6500903072598398827], (-1233526281479424892,-1229710138608978352], (1478830670694875260,1516022971169730278], (5055515752742518226,5080231569691472194], (-8220031638992810484,-8180158125318738371], (-1644262187188908209,-1640818085920683524], (-4203992560184719114,-4201062514351678359], (-5222304299920694120,-5219839223573200521], (-8773724135260117843,-8764792082520695033], (-1355888553876954583,-1337212328034401607], (4736203535340725934,4798689233015535742], (1271210285313194340,1296150437356677365], (-3540891434049035738,-3498615337040509123], (-6469678775729021799,-6460899805527117383], (6720989190599823387,6725081429318018351], (-3498615337040509123,-3498127715533695144], (-3146863944770153663,-3146145879742664566], (1516022971169730278,1543205759172249070], (2435469497781312092,2442862581422161803], (-6451580681320322560,-6450897957558236116], (6401972194395279212,6422279168069398956], (-3185403021559141625,-3146863944770153663], (714305291929584762,737464206890275575], (-8358469817741800124,-8348341616724830280], (1175374807063094969,1214972878391460620], (-7604581392807650182,-7599009809842308024], (737464206890275575,753307058766478061], (6142712373291735013,6158419946524545293], (-4780493053770543287,-4715780574795279713], (-6475595045987094984,-6472782860721811368], (-6000947666680635781,-5984299660747839008], (1296150437356677365,1341203791801750057], (-708535538994856284,-698490751868803865], (7377888475905026189,7453466617724696329], (-6634208348348544983,-6608369916989089358], (6422279168069398956,6425564550565269465], (7864684753798709404,7865351483298068861], (-1142107267252652523,-1130763472498460650], (2661263629361374231,2668692603556301942], (5080231569691472194,5114813438584055434], (-3146145879742664566,-3133020507157500012], (-8847809439930946447,-8773724135260117843], (-7455563937756770941,-7393173741279261649], (-8001929233768101133,-7997359338916453120], (-3208435083108021414,-3185403021559141625], (-8504346858359312144,-8489394145547730314], (330577967974463458,336935533896784347], (7563807678381276197,7582113707662028389], (-8542082760751850432,-8504346858359312144], (-3554430985922725406,-3540891434049035738], (-5146821899868165131,-5132879094583817494], (-240050552784290962,-235772081518906038], (3192195406141461438,3232311876000191165], (4396701296202861119,4435447637968520477], (-6608369916989089358,-6589281199205137237], (-1981758794620356502,-1980394476029734464], (-3563262972235992519,-3554430985922725406], (-8237266126949227268,-8229088751363770412], (4603382773438618005,4650956890538380770], (7199369658829377994,7213887142216841811], (-4962133286795414966,-4960837410336448181], (5732306214090585629,5737923082195078719], (-1640818085920683524,-1638198095283336424], (2953772832389323874,2968606959459466094], (-1235736831018577452,-1234056662103299181], (-8489394145547730314,-8465866933095448418], (-8764792082520695033,-8742184848088246957], (8970234525288431416,8995803891393002810], (-8465866933095448418,-8446751642929552235], (-4836950976239959831,-4798814403290155024], (8821435912538079613,8871870554368996448], (-6636310914487378937,-6634208348348544983], (1127798841363210583,1175374807063094969], (1618461143046543312,1632362492578265392], (4994543089928849457,5055515752742518226], (1593785714944278507,1618461143046543312], (-8885929495137049667,-8847809439930946447], (7514316870399738740,7535648178040640648], (-7997359338916453120,-7884947734877215590], (6848188842228182830,6851091943952222998], (-7468624498429238352,-7467528674261593018], (-5420066870415394025,-5415525963610970555], (-1990341934536435876,-1981758794620356502], (-2119663304358780223,-2025913005077454264], (6951976975129490336,6972519766285293067], (4814028481954927072,4845532697727637101], (6905718428902118395,6951976975129490336], (2442862581422161803,2473486929810000384], (-7050886265796431130,-6984061332646781425], (899736981222314462,902246412094263205], (4181831925595728309,4186043100749193555], (5228334028316552580,5251807687845401107], (7453466617724696329,7514316870399738740], (-5313682991153179320,-5303078638925764028], (4435447637968520477,4466559239870893508], (-1326922053645316997,-1235736831018577452], (1401641821520873210,1444010990722687070], (1751424608310627366,1764837197082917798], (4501052626153108190,4556808478342919483], (4927485308468803128,4934126082298511287], (9034829150987061085,9125279489658634069], (8296589981550156872,8314630209670832253], (8448913759582599761,8531687930406385678], (-6946999157236744448,-6844075271953818452], (1444010990722687070,1478830670694875260], (8959600358987559211,8960859570137987260], (-1336371416389083059,-1326922053645316997], (-61295809418728622,-42017489632420450], (8969118191184771962,8970234525288431416], (1635093197288200819,1646180075666173338], (4934126082298511287,4936412559469748364], (1751396675459233161,1751424608310627366], (-8742184848088246957,-8729944250195454990], (-8229088751363770412,-8220031638992810484], (4598535296351629260,4603382773438618005], (-8174261525446719402,-8163507145438773646], (755491933174209966,772199007723251143], (-8624222028448607604,-8600591663798592212], (-7519020387526209046,-7508903488301733990], (753307058766478061,755491933174209966], (7582113707662028389,7704299093463733587], (8962972620592857243,8969118191184771962], (-3630383383747491969,-3629090531220364683], (-4468127887710219501,-4455300706501649674], (5852098730437702158,5901360113812253268], (-744327910454436920,-731643009820930522], (1911291563147302352,1937039485053092324], (6233932117267819795,6310871518339058610], (-890279568362794135,-887061681980670889], (-3679929070886276718,-3646398519882341977], (670358990995510048,685259738113005224], (4845532697727637101,4882596066849804097], (-6472782860721811368,-6469678775729021799], (-4715780574795279713,-4713529768344258113], (3078864489691764074,3115136329005690845], (9125279489658634069,9133717713662800417], (8960859570137987260,8962972620592857243], (9203390852073803003,-9222340996132828621], (4798689233015535742,4814028481954927072], (-6821121360440227129,-6777406043019946301], (6310871518339058610,6322362350826191135], (-4233493116436171657,-4215258070829115921], (3130822610289703870,3145528043810254358], (5114813438584055434,5123797488219630832], (-6081413019910708044,-6079621320236638978], (8447388029675461333,8448913759582599761], (-3795970094034238564,-3779568630549582632], (-8180158125318738371,-8174261525446719402], (-3844748631754416189,-3795970094034238564], (4113442287147808270,4131576074431163736], (4936412559469748364,4994543089928849457], (4466559239870893508,4501052626153108190], (-3263191959146785290,-3228825867554770158], (6766473197422691050,6766938926557171347], (-8899258035651035854,-8885929495137049667], (-5381097520433537861,-5313682991153179320], (6883419270850869410,6905718428902118395], (5303695175174121453,5306682210025644500], (-9176601682787902008,-9096402285624130055], (-5219839223573200521,-5146821899868165131], (7862240594123780934,7864684753798709404], (6425564550565269465,6447403433784268090], (8996665254881958342,9032628945801968053], (-4912831044277064162,-4902449072491610799], (-2025913005077454264,-1990341934536435876], (-7467528674261593018,-7455563937756770941], (-3293906917083373209,-3283303577982631091], (4186043100749193555,4255028482041276438], (-4902449072491610799,-4875492513338002087], (8531687930406385678,8562083491872293504], (-8600591663798592212,-8567258569010210224], (-6079621320236638978,-6077962914827619257], (-4960837410336448181,-4955223362385024239], (-7634134348451706917,-7604581392807650182], (1632362492578265392,1635093197288200819], (291067515209041750,330577967974463458], (7789905572870286790,7790287256445162065], (-8007287567032110044,-8001929233768101133], (-6971866923830433843,-6946999157236744448], (9032628945801968053,9034829150987061085], (-4798814403290155024,-4780493053770543287], (3905716352976079268,3920453505268467479], (8995803891393002810,8996665254881958342], (-1393787270658712827,-1355888553876954583], (6522490073023565012,6553480210988421066], (7162495952820208409,7199369658829377994], (4882596066849804097,4927485308468803128], (-5893410924582496350,-5858193870200257506], (8233960782654491894,8252708412304213777], (6725081429318018351,6766473197422691050], (-5303078638925764028,-5222304299920694120], (2376875294823216717,2379477119284337609], (-7393173741279261649,-7376038212607696986], (-1337212328034401607,-1336371416389083059], (902246412094263205,902703964241874282], (288868023576418487,291067515209041750], (1341203791801750057,1364316712425392743], (5199663539610295629,5228334028316552580], (6447403433784268090,6476681916885657705], (-3481009398659298196,-3391281017675748608], (4266791030997837989,4315496651682018963], (3115136329005690845,3130822610289703870], (-7599009809842308024,-7598746015885846943]]] Validation failed in /192.168.120.58 (progress: 0%)
```

In this log appears: 
1) `failed with error [repair #7990e900-3a30-11e6-9861-e998758604bf on recommendersjobs/postulationsbyuser` (near the middle)
2) `Validation failed in /192.168.120.58 (progress: 0%)` (in the last part)

While this repair is running (I think it is running), in the log of this node and in the others nodes of the cluster, this appears many times:

```
DEBUG [ReadRepairStage:4] 2016-06-24 14:08:18,318 ReadCallback.java:235 - Digest mismatch:
org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestMismatchException: Mismatch for key DecoratedKey(-3297346077674417080, 42555f31313131303131333538) (d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e vs 9e7f1588ffcd53d13ab3f8bb2be0f05e)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestResolver.resolve(DigestResolver.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ReadCallback$AsyncRepairRunner.run(ReadCallback.java:226) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

NOTE 1: The cassandra was and is working because of the replication factor of 2.
NOTE 2: The cassandra Cluster is being used in production, and applications are inserting and reading rows.

**What can I do to correct this irregular behaviour?

I thought of creating a new node and swap it with the irregular node, what are the correct steps for doing this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a node does not respond / is malfunctioning 
 If you can create a new VM that will repace the malfunctioning node.
See: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

If you do not want to create a new VM and use the existing malfunctioning node. 
**IMPORTANT: NEED TO HAVE A REPLICATION FACTOR THAT ALLOWS YOU TO DELETE ALL THE DATA OF THE AFFECTED NODE**.

```
nodetool decommission (On that node)
```

See: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsDecommission.html

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/*
```

clear/delete all data in the node
See: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/referenceClearCpkgData.html

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

After a time,

```
nodetool repair
```

**If the nodetool repair FAILS:**
For tables in keyspace:

```
nodetool scrub <keyspace> <table>
```

in EACH of the nodes→ see log of the node and wait to complete

```
run nodetool repair <keyspace> <table>
```

only in one node (anyone)

**NOTE:** it is not necessary to run for each table, yo can run:

```
nodetool scrub <keyspace>
```

in EACH of the nodes→ see log of the node and wait to complete

```
nodetool repair <keyspace>
```

I first suggest trying for 1 table for seeing the log of only that table and comprehend better what is going on
**NOTE:** 
set the loggin levels to INFO to see the important things

```
nodetool setlogginglevel org.apache.cassandra INFO
```

Comment: After decommissioning and full clear of the data, you probably need to restart and then **join** the node. Otherwise the node will not be part of the cluster anymore anyway... Also testing the node before re-joining can be a good idea in case something else is awry on that VM. (i.e. bad hard drive, bad network connection, ...)